# How do I target image requests in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to target images in Node.js using path.extname(req.url). I am confused on how to do this because I do not see a request for the image.

What I have is a basic server that fs.readFile on req.url = '/' .. In that file I have html and img tags.  ..... I am console logging req.url, but I dont see a request for the image. All the html loads fine just no request for the image. The only requests logged are : ' / ' and ' favicon.ico '.

I would think that when the page loads , all the **img** tags in that page would load as well , thus requesting "picture.jpg".

My Code:

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer( function(req , res) {

if(req.url == '/') {

    fs.readFile('sample', function(err, data) { 
        res.end(data); }); 
        console.log(req.url); 
        }

        console.log(req.url);





});


server.listen(3000);
console.log('we are in ');
```

SAMPLE page that Node.js reads from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body, html {
height:100%;
}

body {
background:#
margin:0;
}

.container {
height:100%;
width:1024px;
margin: 0 auto;
background:silver;
}

.header {
height:50px;
background:orange;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="header"></div>

<img src="localhost:3000/picture.jpg">



</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Why do I not see the request for the image in the console? If I got that request then I could use path.extname(req.url) to target those extensions and send the images. That is how I am seeing it now.. Please tell me what I am doing/thinking wrong. Thank you

Comment: Have you seen [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/)?

Comment: 1) You should put 'http://' in your img src. 2) You should put some kind of `console.log` call at the top of your request handler to ensure you are in fact not receiving the image request.

Comment: @mscdex YES!! It worked! Thank you! I will remember to put to the protocol before the url next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not making a request to the server because it doesn't know what scheme to use.  Fix it by adding `http://` to the images `src`:

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/picture.jpg">
```